# Random IDs showing up in Firestore collection

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m getting auto generated IDs in my firestore collection even though I’m specifying IDs when creating documents.

I am currently load testing my FastAPI app, currently testing it synchronously. My firestore IDs are coming from a counter stored in firebase’s realtime DB. The counter consists of alphanumeric characters and I’m incrementing them in a transaction. I’m then seeing if a document with that ID exists in firestore, when I find a ID that doesn’t exist I use .set() to create a document with that ID.

```
def increment_realtimedb() -> str:
    try:
        return rdb.transaction(crement)
    except db.TransactionAbortedError:
        increment_realtimedb()


def insert_firestore(payload: dict):
    new_id = increment_realtimedb()
    doc = collection.document(new_id).get()

    while doc.exists:
        new_id = increment_realtimedb()
        doc = collection.document(new_id).get()

    collection.document(new_id).set(payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that increment_realtimedb() was returning None somehow. I changed the while loop to check if new_id was None. That seems to have fixed the problem.

```
while doc.exists or new_id is None:
```

Edit:
After further research it turns out realtime db will return None when you max out the retries for a transaction.